# Calculating area between two curves

Tags: c#, math, graph

I am working on a program that compares two curve (resulted from diode output so its Voltage/Current curve).

I want to calculate the area between this two curves (BLUE curve is first diode and RED is the second one).

[image]

There are 51 data points for each curve (they always have same amount of data poitns). What I am doing at the moment is like this:

```
public double CalculateArea(double[,] pin1, double[,] pin2)
{
    double voltageArea = 0;
    double currentArea = 0; //Current (Vertical axis) not yet!
    double max = 0;
    double min = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < pin1.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        max = Math.Max(Math.Abs(pin1[i, 0]), Math.Abs(pin2[i, 0]));
        min = Math.Min(Math.Abs(pin1[i, 0]), Math.Abs(pin2[i, 0]));

        voltageArea += max - min;
    }

    return voltageArea;
}
```

This code somehow works, having in mind I do nothing with Current (vertical axis). If the result is somehing near 0 eg 0.05 then the difference between curves is negetable. But I am sure this is not the correct way, I totaly have no idea what is the result of the method I wrote...seems to be difference between Voltage points only.

I really appriciate if you can help me improve this method.

Comment: Say hello to [integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral) :)

Comment: Said, but they said bye in return :P I have no idea how can I integrate using only data points

Comment: @Sean87 think about what the integral actually is (and this ties into Nikhil comment)... it is the sum of the areas of numerous infinitely thin rectangles under a curve (illustrated here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Numerical_quadrature_4up.png).  Been so long since I had to do differential calculus, that I would have to work it out on paper before i could write up any code and I don't have enough time right now.  I might check back a bit later and try to help if you are still stuck.

Comment: It will be hard to calculate precise value. What kind of control you using to draw chart?

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks, propably I would need your help:

Comment: @Reniuz I use simply a bitmap to draw on it using 2d graphics...nothing so fancy. I want to make calculations unsing actual data points which are very perecise doubles.

Comment: It won't be hard - this is what numerical integration was born for.  How is it that a person who knows about diodes hasn't been taught the rudiments of differential and integral calculus?  Simpson's rule, Runge-Kutta, Gaussian quadrature - take your pick.

Comment: Never heard of these guys :( I blame the education system

Comment: well first of all doubles is not so precise :)

Comment: @duffymo: Methods like Runge-Kutta for approximating integrals are entirely inappropriate in this case.  The "functions" are piecewise linear so all calculations can be nearly exact.

Comment: Completely inappropriate?  I disagree with that.  You may have a preferred method, but it's not as wrong as you're implying.  Perhaps you don't understand R-K as well as you think you do.

Comment: @duffymo: He has simple functions consisting of straight lines and he wants the area between them.  Runge Kutta is for solving ODEs.  Perhaps I don't understand, but please explain how these two things are related.

Comment: @arx - RK4 can be used to evaluate integrals, in addition to solving ODE's. I am staring at Fortran code that does just this right now.

Comment: Right - what's solving a first order ODE?  Integration, of course.

Comment: @ja72: I stand corrected, you could of course use R-K but it makes as much sense in this case as using R-K to calculate the area of a circle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First subtract one diode from the other do get the difference in values. Then use the trapezoidal rule, which considers the area under a piece-wise linear function.

```
class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Calculate integral with trapezoidal rule
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="h">The step size in x-axis</param>
    /// <param name="y">The array of values to integrate</param>
    /// <returns>The area under the curve y[i,0]</returns>
    public static double Integrate(double h, double[,] y)
    {
        int N=y.GetLength(0);

        double sum=(y[0, 0]+y[N-1, 0])/2;

        for(int i=1; i<N-1; i++)
        {
            sum+=y[i, 0];
        }

        return h*sum;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int N = 100;
        double[,] y=new double[N, 1];

        for(int i=0; i<y.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            y[i, 0]=5+5*Math.Sin(2*Math.PI*i/(N-1));
        }

        double x_min=0.5;
        double x_max=3.5;
        double h = (x_max-x_min)/N;

        double area=Integrate(h, y);
        // expected answer is   area = 15.00
        // actual answer is     area = 14.85
    }
}
```

Comment: I did the same with a cubic spline interpolation, and got an area of 15.000 exactly. Maybe the outputs from the pins are smooth enough to be able to be treated by a cubic spline instead of piece-wise linear.

Comment: Thanks ja, Would you mind explaining a bit more please? What do you mena by substracting diodes? Do you mean individually substract voltage points and current points of each respective data point? Also what should be passes as argument `h` ? what does it mean?

Comment: `h` is the step in the `x`-axis. For each successive measurements if the `x`-axis it time then it is the difference in time. You want to integrate the difference such that `y[i,0] = pin2[i,0]-pin1[i,0]`.